# Is it possible to simply update Firestore object by passing in an object, and letting it figure out what to update specifically?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I've designed my code so that Firebase is hidden from my api services (e.g., `CurrentUserAPIService`), and so if I want to update a user object I'd like to do the following:

```swift
// CurrentUserAPIService.swift
func updateCurrentUser(with currentUser: CurrentUser, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<CurrentUser, APIError>) -> Void) {
        myAPI.updateObject(object: currentUser, withId: currentUser.id, atPath: .users) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("Success")
                completionHandler(.success(currentUser))

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

which would call my API class to do the following:

```swift
// MyAPI.swift
func updateObject<T: Encodable>(object: T, withId objectId: String, atPath path: Path, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Void, APIError>) -> Void) {
        let documentReference = Firestore.firestore().collection(path.rawValue).document(objectId)

        do {
            try documentReference.updateData(object, completion: { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completionHandler(.failure(.generic(message: error.localizedDescription)))
                } else {
                    completionHandler(.success(()))
                }
            })

        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completionHandler(.failure(.generic(message: error.localizedDescription)))
        }
    }
```

Is this possible? I'd like a way to pass through the full object and have a helper function figure out what to actually upload automatically, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use the updateData syntax, you should write a wrapper around `setData()`. And there is no way for Firestore to know what you want to update. `merge:true` will make sure any fields on the local copy overwrite the database copy. It will NOT delete any fields from the database.

```
extension DocumentReference {
    func updateData<T: Encodable>(for object: T, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        do {
            try self.setData(from: object, merge: true) { err in
                completion(err)
            }
        } catch {
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super useful, but make sure you know the object exists. This doesn't work like the regular updateData( func where it will return an error if the item doesn't exist.